# Incomplete normal modal logic systems

Tags: modal-logic

Apart from the classical example of KH, given by axiom $\Box(\Box p\leftrightarrow p)\to \Box p$, are there any other examples of incomplete propositional normal modal logic systems defined by axioms in 1 variable and of modal degree $\le 2$?
If so, I would also appreciate a reference to where the proofs can be found. I am looking for the simplest possible examples. Van Benthem's is of modal degree 3, others are in 2 variables etc.

Comment: You might be able to find what you're after in Priest's *An Introduction to Non-Classical Logic: From If to Is*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found in the Volume 3 of the *Handbook of Philosophical Logic, 2nd Edition*, 2001. See the "Correspondence Theory" chapter by Johan van Benthem, pp. 325-408. On page 333, Fact 5, he gives an example of an incomplete modal logic:

The logic $L$ that extends $\mathbf{K}$ with axioms (of degree at most 2 and with only 1 variable)
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\Box p\to p\\
\Box\Diamond p\to\Diamond\Box p\\
\Box(p\to\Box p)\to(\Diamond p\to p)
\end{array}
$$
is even first-order definable, as it defines the class of frames satisfying the first-order sentence $\forall x\forall y(xRy\leftrightarrow x=y)$, but the modal formula ${\Box p\leftrightarrow p}$, which is valid on this class of frames, is not derivable in $L$. Therefore, the logic $L$ is not Kripke complete.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In the meantime I had found this system myself, and I suspected it was incomplete, only I was not able to prove(see [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/168244/is-this-system-incomplete)) that ${\Box p\leftrightarrow p}$ is not a theorem, which seems to be the hard part. I understand the proof is in van Benthem's 1978 paper "Two simple incomplete modal logics", which I do not have. If anyone can sketch the proof here I would be interested.

Comment: Here is van Benthem's 1978 paper: [mirror1](http://libgen.org/scimag/get.php?doi=10.1111%2Fj.1755-2567.1978.tb00830.x) | [mirror2](http://lib.gen.in/5b37e7eabac4f779dc15a75dd8da46ef.pdf)  Also you will find the following paper relevant to your question: "A Simple Incomplete Extension of T which is the Union of Two Complete Modal Logics with f.m.p." by Roy A. Benton (2002): [link](http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/A:1021223721102).